# Draw a frame with textures in libgdx

Tags: android, opengl-es, libgdx, blending

I am trying to draw a frame with two textures within Libgdx. My texture is just a white square that i scale and draw with SpriteBatch to the screen. The color is set with `batch.setColor()`. Now I want to draw a black rectangle and a smaller opaque rectangle in the middle, so it looks like a frame.

```
batch.begin();
batch.setColor(new Color(0,0,0,1)); //Black
batch.draw(rectangle, 0,0,100,100);
batch.setColor(new Color(0,0,0,0)); //Transparent
batch.draw(rectangle, 25,25,50,50);
batch.end();
```

I am using this blend function:
`Gdx.gl.glBlendFunc(GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_COLOR);`
the problem now is when i draw this it just shows the black rectangle cause the transparent rectangle is drawn on top of it. I want to draw it that I can see through the second rectangle the stuff I drawed before so it acts like a frame.
My question is: How can i accomplish this?

[Example Background](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dXTXu.png)

[How it should look](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dadgc.png)

[How it looks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hBuR4.png)

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you should not create new instances of Color in your `render()` method, since it's called every frame it will lead to a memory leak. Create colors in `create()` for example. And for black color you could use Color.BLACK instead of creating your own instance.

Back to your question. 
You can simply just use `TextureRegion` class. Here is a sample code:

```
public class MyGdxGame extends ApplicationAdapter {

    SpriteBatch batch;
    Texture whiteRectangle;
    TextureRegion backgroundRegion;

    @Override
    public void create() {
        //initializing batch, whiteTexture, etc...

        //background, the one with a turtle from you example
        Texture backgroundTexture = ...;

        backgroundRegion = new TextureRegion(backgroundTexture);
        //to set a region (part of the texture you want to draw),
        //you can use normalized coordinates (from 0 to 1), or absolute values in pixels
        backgroundRegion.setRegion(0.25f, 0.25f, 0.75f, 0.75f);
    }

    @Override
    public void render() {
        Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 1);
        Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
        batch.begin();

        //black background
        batch.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        batch.draw(whiteRectangle, 0, 0, 100, 100);

        //on top of that background draw the backgroundRegion
        batch.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        batch.draw(backgroundRegion, 25,25,50,50);

        batch.end();
    }

}
```